# Approximation of a 2 variable function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If the weight of an object that does not float in water is $x$ pounds in the air and its weight in water is $y$ pounds , then the specific gravity of the object is :
$S= \dfrac{x}{x-y}$

For a certain object x and y are measured to be 1.2lbs and 0.5lbs. It is known that the measuring instrument will not register less than the true weights , but it could register more than the true weights by as much as 0.01lbs.

We need to find the maximum possible error is $S$.

Maximum possible error in $S$ is represented as $\dfrac{\Delta S}{S}$ , and ,

$\Delta S = S_x \Delta x+ S_y \Delta y$

The question says ,

> "It is known that the measuring instrument will not register less than
>   the true weights , but it could register more than the true weights by
>   as much as 0.01lbs."

So what I gathered from this was , $\Delta x \leq 0.01$ , similarly $\Delta y \leq 0.01$ , but couldn't get the correct answer ..

Am I speculating wrong ?

Kindly help !

Comment: Can you show what you have calculated ? You are right, that $\Delta x \leq 0.01$ and $\Delta y \leq 0.01$. To find the max you calculate with $\Delta x = 0.01$ and $\Delta y = 0.01$

Comment: $S_x = \dfrac{-y}{x-y}$ and $S_y = \dfrac{x}{x-y}$ ,
thus , $\Delta S = \dfrac{-y}{x-y} \Delta x+\dfrac{x}{x-y} \Delta y$

Dividing by S yields :

$\dfrac{\Delta S}{S} = \dfrac{-y}{x-y}\dfrac{ \Delta x}{x}+\dfrac{y}{x-y} \dfrac{\Delta y}{y}$

Comment: Am I right till now ? @calculus

Comment: the derivative of a fraction $f(x)=\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}$ is $f'(x)=\frac{u'(x)v(x)-v'(x)u(x)}{(v'(x))^2}$. You have forgotten the square in the denominator.

Comment: Sorry , forgot about that , but still , doesn't affect the solution :( @calculus

Comment: And $$\frac{ \Delta S}{S}=\frac{1}{S}\cdot \left( \frac{-y}{(x-y)^2}\cdot \Delta x+  \frac{x}{(x-y)^2}\cdot \Delta y \right)$$. You do not divide by x or y. just divide by S. Note that you had a typo at the second fraction (numerator). It is an x instead of an y.

Comment: By using the formula above I get $\frac{\Delta S}{S}=\frac{1}{120}$

Comment: Got the same result.. But the solution says "0.014".. @calculus

Comment: It seems that this is the result of $\Delta S$. The calculation is $\frac{-y}{(x-y)^2}\cdot \Delta x+  \frac{x}{(x-y)^2}\cdot \Delta y=(-0.5/0.7^2*0.01+1.2/0.7^2*0.01)\approx 0.0143$ Maybe it was your Interpretation, that you have to calculate the relative error.

Comment: Okay , finally got it.. Thanks a ton !@calculus

Comment: Fine. You are welcome.